# Using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFLE for reading XML files

Tags: mysql, xml

I know using LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE for reading XML files.
but i do not need to separate xml elements. I like to import whole xml file as a text.
Is it possible reading whole XML file as a text file?

I used this command

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.xml' INTO TABLE mytable;
```

the result is:

> The query has been successfully implemented, 150 rows have been
>   affected.

But when i use `SELECT * FROM mytable;` it shows 150 empty lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.xml' INTO TABLE mytable
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\n'  LINES STARTING BY '';
```

just replace `FIELDS TERMINATED BY` value & `LINES STARTING BY` value as per your file.

Comment: Well Done! i used below command and it worked!
`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.xml'  INTO TABLE mytable FIELDS TERMINATED BY '' ENCLOSED BY '' ESCAPED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY ''`